# Git - Gitlab branches

Tags: git

I cloned a project from gitlab and I created some branches to work on , but when I visit the branches page in gitlab I can't see my new branches which I have created even when I do changes and commit them I can't see any commit .. What should I do to see them in the repo ?

Comment: Have you pushed the new branches from local to remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a branch on git, it only exists locally until you push it.

Git won't push a new branch automatically, even if you use the `git push` command without any option.

You need to push the branch to the remote.

```
git push origin mybranch
```

should do the trick.